# SQL Dynamic Condense

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to produce a dynamic query to condense query results and speed up performance in one of our sites.

The question is given this table (condensed from a large field-set):

```
======================================
|   id  | team_id | game_no | result |
--------------------------------------
|  1012 |    1    |   1     |   178  |
|  1132 |    1    |   2     |   122  |
|  1514 |    1    |   3     |   166  |
|  1519 |    2    |   1     |   155  |
|  1761 |    2    |   2     |   111  |
|  2030 |    2    |   3     |   222  |
|  2037 |    2    |   4     |   225  |
======================================
```

I need to construct a SQL query that produces the following output:

```
RESULT:
=======================================================
| team_id | game_1 | game_2 | game_3 | game_4 | total |
|    1    |   178  |   122  |   166  |    0   |  466  |
|    2    |   155  |   111  |   222  |   225  |  713  |
=======================================================
```

However, the number of games changes dynamically depending on another field in another table in the database, there may not always be 4 games there could be 8 or 10.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I forgot to say! The site is a PHP based WebApp, so happy to integrate to achieve a solution!

Comment: You need to get the max game no value from the table, and write a dynamic query ultimately

Comment: That is where my brain is stumped, as I have that value stored but not sure how to construct the dynamic query...

Comment: ok give me thirty mins I'll try do it

Comment: Thanks @AbBennett, life saver!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible, but it's certainly going to be involved. SQL databases have a basic assumption that columns belong to schema (which is rather static) whereas rows belong to data (dynamic). The entire relational algebra is built on that assumption. So my suggestion would be to avoid doing this in the database if possible and do it in code. Even if you succeed, SQL will probably be ugly, non-portable, inefficient and unreadable. I'd be delighted to see somebody disprove this.

Comment: appreciate the insight @jurez the whole idea of this table was to avoid a table with 100+ columns as this is the max number of game possibilities. I have another possible "solution", however wanted to see this method has a potential solution.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't use SQL server, however Ab has given me guidance based on his knowledge area. This answer has led me to a potential solution. I will be reversing that change

Comment: fiar enough you revert the change. But the answer with SQL-server code should not be accepted to this question because the question is tagged as MySQL.. this will lead to misunderstanding later on with readers in the future.

Comment: @RaymondNijland now you explain it, I have reapplied that change. However, I have left mysql as a tag for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer using tsql in sql server. I know you are using mysql, but it should give an idea and should be doable in mysql procedural language equivalent (I assume there is one). The TSQL code below produces the following sql and executes it

```
select teamid,
       sum(CASE WHEN gameno=1 then result else 0 end) g_1 ,
       sum(CASE WHEN gameno=2 then result else 0 end) g_2 ,
       sum(CASE WHEN gameno=3 then result else 0 end) g_3 ,
       sum(CASE WHEN gameno=4 then result else 0 end) g_4 ,
       sum(result) total 
 from #ab 
 group by teamid
```

this is the tsql code, you need to run to make dynamic query

```
declare @l_sql varchar(4000)= 'select teamid'
declare @l_gameno int

DECLARE l_cursor CURSOR 
FOR
  select distinct gameno from #ab order by 1
OPEN l_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM l_cursor INTO @l_gameno
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   set @l_sql = @l_sql + ',sum(CASE WHEN gameno='+cast(@l_gameno as varchar)+' then result else 0 end) g_'+cast(@l_gameno as varchar)+' ' 
   FETCH NEXT FROM l_cursor INTO @l_gameno
end 
CLOSE l_cursor
DEALLOCATE l_cursor
set @l_sql = @l_sql + ',sum(result) total from #ab group by teamid'
exec (@l_sql)
```